# Prime Numbers and Multiples?

Tags: prime-numbers

Other than prime numbers are all numbers multiple of 2,3,5 and 7 (Other Prime numbers as well). Suppose like if we need 8 it's the combination of 2.2.2, and 15 as 5.3 etc.

Comment: No, 11 is not. Neither is 143 = 11 * 13.

Comment: Well, the smallest counterexample is $1$. The next is $121$.

Comment: yes that's why i said OTHER THAN prime numbers. and 121 is combination of 11.11

Comment: Not unless you're an [engineer](http://www.phy.ilstu.edu/~rfm/107f07/epmjokes.html).

Comment: But $1$ is not prime. And $11$ is not one of $2,3,5,7$.

Comment: I don't see any question here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No: 
$$11\cdot 13 = 143$$

$$13 \cdot 17 = 221$$

$$\vdots$$

The most we can say is what the **[Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic)** tells us: Every integer greater than $1$ is a prime number or a product of prime numbers.

**Edit**: (Revised question) Yes, except $1$ is neither prime nor is it a product of prime numbers.

Comment: That's what i am saying we achive every number with the combination of prime numbers? right?

Comment: Yes, every number is a product of prime numbers or else is a prime: but there are infinitely many prime numbers other than $2, 3, 5, 7$.

Comment: @amWhy: Links and all +1

Comment: @amWhy: I love that $\vdots$ above +

Comment: @Babak $\quad \overset{\large\vdots\;}{\cdots} + \vdots + \underset{\large\;\vdots}{\cdots}$

Answer (score 2):

No, $1763 = 41 \times 43$. For example, if you multiply any two primes other than $2,3,5$ and $7$ (note there are infinitely many primes), you get a number that is "not a combination of" $2,3,5$ or $7$.

Answer (score 1):

No .  Fundamental theorem of arithmetic states that every integer greater than 1 is either prime itself or is the product of prime numbers
examples:
$22 = 11 \cdot 2$
$1200 = 2^4 \cdot 3 \cdot 5^2 $

Answer (score 1):

It's not like that.

Every positive integer(non-prime) is always a multiple of other primes smaller than that.

But it doesn't mean that those will surely have 2,3,5,&7.

for  example you can take:

$121=11\times11$